# Why are my card-views' positions fixed despite me moving their positions in XML?

Tags: java, android, xml

I created an android layout that utilizes `CardView.` However, I also created a `TextView` that's supposed to go on top of the `CardViews.` However, I noticed that the `TextView` overlapped on one of the cards so I went and changed the card's position(which is contained in a reliant layout)  in XML. However, I ran it again and nothing changed. I'd greatly appreciate if you'd show me how to correct my error.

**XML code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_welcome_page"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/redbck"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.avinashdavid.trivialtrivia.UI.ActivityWelcomePage"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <LinearLayout
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:gravity="center_horizontal">


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_start_game"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00d4ff">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer1"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_start"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecontainer1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/startgame"
                        style="@style/WelcomeHeadings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/start_game"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/StatsContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/start_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_statistics"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00d4ff">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer2"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_statistics"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecontainer2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/WelcomeHeadings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Online Mode"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/StatsContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/statistics_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_statistics2"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00d4ff">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer22"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_statistics2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecontainer22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/WelcomeHeadings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Online Mode"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/StatsContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/statistics_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_instructions"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00d4ff">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer3"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_instructions"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecontainer3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/WelcomeHeadings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Report a Bug"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/StatsContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/instructions_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_acknowledgments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00d4ff">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_acknowledgments"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecontainer4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/WelcomeHeadings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Terms and Conditions"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/StatsContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/acknowledgements_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Select a Game Mode"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to just replace your main `RelativeLayout` to `LinearLayout` and

Place `TextView` to top. have a look at below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_welcome_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/redbck"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.avinashdavid.trivialtrivia.UI.ActivityWelcomePage">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Select a Game Mode"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_start_game"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00d4ff">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_start"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecontainer1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/startgame"
                        style="@style/WelcomeHeadings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/start_game"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/StatsContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/start_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view_acknowledgments"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00d4ff">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/imagecontainer4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:paddingStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_acknowledgments"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imagecontainer4"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/WelcomeHeadings"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Terms and Conditions"
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        style="@style/StatsContent"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                        android:text="@string/acknowledgements_subtitle"
                        android:textColor="#fff" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You helped me out immeasurably!

Comment: @MikeIke my pleasure. You can **upvote** my answer too. :-)